# CentOS 7 cPanel - Setting Correct Permissions

Tags: permissions

I have a pre existing server running whm/cpanel which has a Wordpress site that needs to be moved to its own server.

I have move the files and database across and everything is ready except for a few errors that certain directories are not writeable by a particular plugin.

On the original server everything is stored under /home/frt (created by adding a new account in WHM). The user is frt and the group is frt. The directories are set to 755 and files to 644.

I have setup the new server in exactly the same way, so I cannot figure out why I am getting these errors. They only disappear if I set permissions to 777 on the relevant folders. 775 does not work either.

Another thing I have noticed is there is no apache user or group on the new server, nut there is on the original CentOS 6 server.

I have little experience with CentOS, usually I use Debian so I'm not sure how things should work or if this is actually correct.

Can someone advise me how I can get the permissions set correctly?

The Errors are:

> ERROR: Path ../wp-content/connection_images does not seem to be writeable.
>   
> ERROR: Path ../wp-content/connections_templates does not seem to be writeable.
>   
> ERROR: Path ../wp-content/plugins/connections/cache does not seem to be writeable.

Comment: You can read about the recommended permissions on [this page](https://wordpress.org/support/article/changing-file-permissions/#permission-scheme-for-wordpress). Permissions depend on whether WP runs using default shared server username or not?

Comment: Try to chown -R 48:48 usually that's Apache